# Another riddle about something abstract that has been stolen

Tags: riddle, word, steganography

Ob*v*iously something is quite wrong. Right before midnight, **an** ill-looking ogre, env*i*ous of our colorful world, stole a color. Apparently that **does** not make any **sense**, but this is my riddle, s*o* get over **it**. Not that I care - because I **do** not, really. Granted, this pecu*l*iar thief knew his job, since he gave the correct **password** to th*e* guard ("berry", "shift" and "lagoon"). Enough talking, can you *t*ell me which color was stolen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Taking the first letter of each sentence gives us Orange, and since something was stolen, it seems we are trying to find a set of colours, with one missing. 
>  O'gre en'vious spells green, with Envy being associated with Green - Thanks to OnlyF for this bit 
>  As Mnemonic points out (to my chagrin) the dots and dashes spell out Red (I kept missing Ill-looking's dash). 
>  The passwords point to Blue, from Blue-berry, Blue-Shift, and Blue-Lagoon 
>  So far Blue, Violet, Green, Red and Orange have been found, so I am now looking for Yellow or Indigo, the Bold text isn't jumping out at me yet though.

For the final part:

> The distances between bold words (including the words themselves) are 9, 14, 4, 9, 7, 15, which are the indices of "indigo". - Again thanks to Mnumonic

So the answer must be:

> Yellow

Mnumonic clearly helped a lot here, so I would like to request that any voters also give him his due

Comment: As you guessed, it is not that simple ;)

Comment: Right, now lets get into the real puzzle then :p

Comment: "The troll was ill looking, implying Green": nothing is merely implied, it has to be sturdier than this ;). And it's an ogre.

Comment: Maybe also rot13(terra bs rail + b'ter ra'ivbhf fcryyf terra)?

Comment: I think I've got the last one in my answer.

Comment: I believe so, likely earning you the tick. Nicely done, I was a few minutes at least from that last Bold leap...

Comment: Since you both contributed to the answer, I use to give the tick for the one posting the complete explanation (with due respect to helpers), so go ahead ;)

Answer (score 18):

Adding onto Fifth_H0r5eman's answer,

> The dots and dashes spell out "red" in Morse code.

Also,

> The distances between bold words (including the words themselves) are 9, 14, 4, 9, 7, 15, which are the indices of "indigo".

That just leaves

> Yellow

as the stolen color.

Comment: My god, I was trying to get that to fit, but Rot13(zvffrq gur qnfu va vyy-ybbxvat) every time...

Answer (score 0):

The color stolen was :

> violet

Because:

> All the italicized letters in the text spell violet